Add additional php.ini on a shared server
I want to have display_errors=on in php.ini to get more information than just "500" when developing php scripts for my website on a shared server.
I learned this requires a modification of php.ini, which is not possible in my case.
phpinfo reports
Loaded Configuration File                /etc/php8.2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  (none)

Of course I cannot modify files on /etc/php8.2/
At least I can read it and find display_errors=off there.
How's the syntax for ini_set to add an own directory to scan for an additional php.ini  ?
I notice that very dumb syntax errors (e.g. missing semicolon) aren't captured by
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", getcwd() . "/php-error.log");

because they happen at compile time, long before ini_set (and even .htaccess settings) etc. are executed

If this is a shared hosting server and is internet-facing, probably it's set to log errors to a file instead of show them on screen - this is sensible both for security and for a better user experience. If you can't find where the PHP log file is located to look at errors, contact the system's administrator / support helpdesk.

If you are serving the website over PHP-FPM then you could use a .user.ini

If you server supports the use of .htaccess files you could try to add custom settings in this file e.g. php_value display_errors 1.

P.S. For development work you are far better to have a development environment on your own machine, with PHP etc installed. Then you can configure that to display errors directly in the output, if you find that easier. Once your script is developed and tested you can deploy it to the server for real use by users. This makes it easier to dev and test things, doesn't risk causing interference with your real environment, and means it's easier to work on enhancing a script while the current one is still in active use. Developing directly on the server is a very sub-optimal solution.

If you are using WordPress you could try using my plugin which supports changing PHP settings using either and .htaccess or .user.ini file: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-php-settings/

This question is similar to: How can I get useful error messages in PHP?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also, it might be interesting to use a tool like Sentry to log such errors into a tool where you can look them up better than in any textual log file, and way better than showing all raw error messages to your customers

Thanks @Cyclonecode, @ADyson and @Nico Haase for your hints.
Installing my own web server and PHP and eventually a database with test data would be better on the long run, sure. My only security measure to hide the broken page from other users is a temporary and not yet linked page name. Not too professional, I confess. An editor with better php syntax checking than notepad++ might be another hint. The additional ini_set methods mentioned in the link by @Nico just changed the format of the HTTP CODE 500 response, bad luck.
I tried all the stuff I found so far, including the .htaccess approach without success (have access to it and can e.g. configure a 404-page)
But I found another solution (somewhere on stackoverflow ?), not mentioned yet: If the syntax error is inside an include file, it is reported on the screen. No matter if the erroneous function is called.
Sample:
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title> PHP Test Environment </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", getcwd() . "/php-error.log");
function shutDownFunction() {
    echo "shutdown_function running";
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR) print_r ($error);
}
register_shutdown_function('shutDownFunction');

include './db_functions.php';  // supplies connect(), getID(), getTimeSeries() 
try {
  include './error.php';  // Syntax error in there is reported on screen
  $db = connect(); 
  if ($db) echo "Connected ! <br>";
  $ID = getID($db, "Gesamt");
  $pos = 6;
  $time = '2024-06-26';
  echo json_encode(getTimeSeries($db, $ID, $pos, $time, 4));
  $db -> close();
  // x  // if comment removed, error here is not shown, simply reporting `HTTP ERROR 500`
} catch (\Throwable $t) {
     echo $t->getMessage(), " at ", $t->getFile(), ":", $t->getLine(), "<br>";
}
?>
<p>Done</p>
</body>

This is the included file error.php:
<?php
function wrong_getID(&$db) {
    xyz // error here
    $ID = 0;
    $q = "SELECT ID FROM Device WHERE Name='xyz'";
    $result = $db->query($q);
    if ($result && $result->num_rows == 1) 
        $ID = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)[0];
    return $ID;
}
?>

So putting all php code into an included file and just adding the
try {} catch (throwable) on the page itself might help.

"SELECT ID FROM Device WHERE Name='".$name."';" - please be warned that such queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

See How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement to help with what Nico said

Correct. That's just to supply a complete sample with few rows to read. Sorry that it immediately makes your bells ring. ;)

Of course it does. Keep in mind you're not only posting an answer for yourself, but also for others and that the code provided in the answer is insecure

I posted a  sample of wrong code, which I changed now, to be rather useless but no longer insecure, when the error is fixed. Another issue, posting error messages to users,  is questionable as well and should be removed when publishing.

    xyz // error here - that looks obvious to me: the code can't be parsed

You're right, @Nico Haase, that's the topic of this issue: How to make php code reveal it's errors. If it fails compiling, all the code dealing with logging etc does not help. sample code should be obvious. The solution/workaround is to have that questionable code in an included file.
Using an editor with better php syntax checking was suggested in the comments to the question.
